# image not found / can't get /uploads/image nodejs REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to send an image to client in nodejs/expressjs REST API. What I am trying to do is saving that image url in mongo db database. When user make a get request, I send all the necessary data alongside the image which is basically avatar. Now on the client side I am not able to receive that image. I am keep getting below responses.

[image]

in console tab of chrome dev tools I am getting below.

[image]

When I see in the network tab I get below response which also has the link to avatar. Everything is perfect here.

[image]

Now when I check my uploads folder I do have the image. Check below:

[image]

After all this I am still getting these errors and still not sure where exactly am I making mistake. One thing is that maybe the client is trying to make a request to /uploads/image end point which I do not want. I simply want that image to be displayed using the url I am getting on response.

Comment: Images do not help here... Please post some code here stats what you tried so far...

Comment: Not have enough information. But i think, you are not saving image with extension.

Answer (score 2):

As we do not see the configuration of static files in express, this might be the problem.

To serve static files in your `/uploads` folder you need to add this line

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'uploads' directory will not be accessible from the frontend.

In node, move the uploaded file in to a subdirectory of the public directory of the node app, and set a relative path from there ans the image path.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#:%7E:text=const%20path%20%3D%20require(%27path%27)%0Aapp.use(%27/static%27%2C%20express.static(path.join(__dirname%2C%20%27public%27)))), to be on the safe side you should append the absolute path of the image or directory you want to serve.

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))
```

Comment: Hi, your answer iis a duplicate of [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50799646/7353417)